# Data passing problem from a class to a activity

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, spp

newbie to android !
basically i trying to make a proprietary app for my product which runs on BT SPP Protocol !
so i decided use https://github.com/akexorcist/BluetoothSPPLibrary  a class which handles bt service for outgoing / incoming data from bt device

Sending data is ok !
but when i trying receiving data simply cannot call / receive data inside activity class

here is my snippets of my code !

**BTSpp.java**

```java
 public interface OnDataReceivedListener {
        public void onDataReceived(byte[] data, String message);  /// for sending back data to the activity 
    }

...

//this is not executing cause log is not running when receives data

public void setOnDataReceivedListener (OnDataReceivedListener listener) {
        Log.d("TAG", "setOnDataReceivedListener() returned: " );
        if(null == mDataReceivedListener)
            mDataReceivedListener = listener;
    }
...
//Here is the snippet for reading data from bt service and 
//it is showing log whenever i receives data from spp device 

case BluetoothState.MESSAGE_READ:

                    byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                    String readMessage = new String(readBuf);

                    if(readBuf != null && readBuf.length > 0) {
                        if(mDataReceivedListener != null){
                            Log.d("TAG", "handleMessage() returned: "+mDataReceivedListener ); //executes
                            mDataReceivedListener.onDataReceived(readBuf, readMessage);}
                    }
                    break;
```

and in my activity window onCreate method
not at all executing this method
**MainActivity.java**

```
BluetoothSPP bt=new BluetoothSPP(this); //initialized

{...}
bt.setOnDataReceivedListener(new BluetoothSPP.OnDataReceivedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataReceived(byte[] data, String message) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onDataReceived() returned: " );
                Log.i(TAG, "onDataReceived: "+message);
                Log.i(TAG, "onDataReceived: "+data);
                processIncomingdata(message);
            }
        });
```

maybe this function doesn't call from service class . i literally can't find any clue !
can anyone give me some suggestion about this !

Thank you in advance !

Comment: What's the problem here? Your code looks fine to me. ***this is not executing cause log is not running when receives data***? Of course, it is running when call the method in `MainActivity.java`.

Comment: Thank u fr replying !
yes every other methods that is uses this type of call backs method those are working fine except this !
bt.setOnDataReceivedListener(new BluetoothSPP.OnDataReceivedListener() {}

as far i know this by default get called from service class ! but not getting executed !

Comment: ***... as far i know this by default get called from service class ...*** It is completely false. Why would it be called by default by a service. You'll need to show more of your code especially your ***service*** class for us to understand what's really going on.

Comment: here is original source code of the service library !
[BTService](https://github.com/akexorcist/BluetoothSPPLibrary/blob/master/library/src/main/java/app/akexorcist/bluetotohspp/library/BluetoothSPP.java)

and here is my source code -- 
[dashboard](https://pastebin.com/5umvJfM0)

Comment: Does `onDataReceived()` get called after all? If not there 
must be something wrong in `BluetoothState.MESSAGE_READ`.

Comment: Solved ! the issue is elsewhere !
i wrongly handled strings !
now it's working !
but Thank you for helping :) !